# How to specify format with snap run youtube-dl?

Tags: video, snap, downloads, youtube

I tried

```
snap run youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0TwYwqiQ9E
```

Got

```
[youtube] g0TwYwqiQ9E: Downloading webpage
[info] Available formats for g0TwYwqiQ9E:
format code  extension  resolution note
249          webm       audio only tiny   62k , opus @ 50k (48000Hz), 6.35MiB
250          webm       audio only tiny   80k , opus @ 70k (48000Hz), 8.43MiB
140          m4a        audio only tiny  128k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k (44100Hz), 16.98MiB
251          webm       audio only tiny  148k , opus @160k (48000Hz), 16.91MiB
278          webm       256x144    144p   99k , webm container, vp9, 30fps, video only, 11.84MiB
160          mp4        256x144    144p  112k , avc1.4d400c, 30fps, video only, 6.44MiB
133          mp4        426x240    240p  215k , avc1.4d4015, 30fps, video only, 11.62MiB
242          webm       426x240    240p  226k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 18.12MiB
243          webm       640x360    360p  413k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 31.77MiB
134          mp4        640x360    360p  580k , avc1.4d401e, 30fps, video only, 27.32MiB
244          webm       854x480    480p  765k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 51.62MiB
135          mp4        854x480    480p 1160k , avc1.4d401f, 30fps, video only, 51.69MiB
247          webm       1280x720   720p 1525k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 103.96MiB
136          mp4        1280x720   720p 2313k , avc1.4d401f, 30fps, video only, 103.16MiB
18           mp4        640x360    360p  433k , avc1.42001E, 30fps, mp4a.40.2@ 96k (44100Hz), 57.93MiB
22           mp4        1280x720   720p  898k , avc1.64001F, 30fps, mp4a.40.2@192k (44100Hz) (best)
```

There is no download. How to specify format code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download a video with, for example, the format code 136, you run

```
youtube-dl -f 136 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0TwYwqiQ9E
```